# Need+to be OR needed+to be

Tags: verbs, passive-voice, needs-pp

Which of the following full sentences is correct?

> 1. Our voice needs to be heard by the media.
> 2. Our voice is needed to be heard by the media.

It sounds to me as if they are both the same and giving a passive voice.

Comment: Neither is grammatical (at least not in the sense you’re most likely going for).

Comment: The question is too broad. Please limit the question by supplying the context together with why you disagree with the standard interpretation within that context.

Comment: what if I add (by): here we have the full sentences : Our voice needs to be heard by the media  OR Our voice is needed to be heard by the media---- it sounds to me they are same and giving a passive voice-- And many thanks for the comments I appreciate ..

Comment: Neither is wrong: which is correct depends on its precise context & usage - which you have not supplied.  I've also edited your Q. to incorporate the clarification from your comment.  But I'm still voting to close this Q.!

Comment: yes This answer is helpful

Answer (score 2):

This question is better suited to our sister-site [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) (English Language Learners) but in case it doesn't get migrated here's an answer.

"Our voice" is singular, so the verb that follows must be in the [third-person singular](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/third-person_singular) (Wiktionary)

> Our voice need**s** to be heard

As to your second sentence, which is in the simple present passive voice, it's grammatical but its meaning is slightly redundant.

> Our voice **is** needed to be heard

The speaker is saying their voice is necessary for it to be heard by someone or something, which I suppose makes sense. But I think the OP is looking to say the following

> Our voice **must** be heard

See [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=needs%20to%20be%20heard%2Cneeded%20to%20be%20heard%2Cmust%20be%20heard&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cneeds%20to%20be%20heard%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cneeded%20to%20be%20heard%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmust%20be%20heard%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cneeds%20to%20be%20heard%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Cneeded%20to%20be%20heard%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Cmust%20be%20heard%3B%2Cc1) chart below for confirmation

[image]

Comment: the answers are not helpful...somebody please help

Comment: @user342858 You fixed the grammar in the first example because I explained the error. You added the object (by the media) because I said the second sentence was confusing. I told you that the second sentence was in the passive voice. I showed that the phrase "voice must be heard" is much more common.... I think you should be pretty happy but I can delete the answer if you prefer.

Comment: It is helpful neither to yourself nor to others who may consider answering your Q. if you do not say WHY "the answers are not helpful".